# LIMIT LEFT JOIN TO ONE RECORD FROM ADDED TABLE

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

Now the result is  that it`s showing same post as many times as many photos it has.
What to limit times of viewing same news??

```
function get_all_news(){ 
   $query = $this->db->select('news.*, news_photos.name as news_photo_name, news_photos.ext as news_photo_ext')->from('news')->join('news_photos', 'news.id = news_photos.id_news', 'left')->order_by("date", "desc")->get();   
}
```

Comment: use a group by clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use DISTINCT or a GROUP BY on news.id.